# Windows 7 forgets my default settings

Tags: windows-7, user-interface

I recently bought a new computer and Windows 7 Home Premium. I only have one small problem though. I have the option "Show Window Contents While Dragging" enabled, but everytime I restart the computer, it reverts back to DISabled.

The only thing i could think of is the system requirements etc. But this is not the case as my computer more than meets the full requirements.

Can somebody help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

look in the eventlog for profile problems!

Comment: Hmm, looks like I'll need to create a new User Account (don't know why, i only bought this computer the other day and haven't installed anything on it yet.) - Is there a way so that all programs that i've MADE and settings get transferred to the new profile?